# $\nabla \cdot (b \nabla c) = 0$ where $b$ and $c$ are unknown

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vectors, vector-analysis, boundary-value-problem

**Description:**

I want to solve the equation
$$ \nabla \cdot \left( b \nabla c \right) = 0 $$
for $b(x,y)$ and $c(x,y)$ in the domain $x,y \geq 0$. This partial differential equation is supplemented by
$$ b \nabla c = \vec{g} $$
where $\vec{g}(x,y)$ is a known vector that has non-zero curl. Furthermore, the values of $b$ and $c$ are known on the boundary $(x = 0, y = 0)$. As a consequence, the normal derivatives of $c(x,y)$ on the boundary are also known:
$$ \nabla \times \vec{g} = R(x,y) \ne 0 \\
c = 0 \hspace{4mm} \text{at} \hspace{4mm} x=0 \\
c = 0 \hspace{4mm} \text{at} \hspace{4mm} y=0 \\ $$

What solution methods to this problem exist? Can you point me to any resources? If I try to solve this numerically, which software packages can you recommend? Thanks.

It is possible to derive the first-order pde's
$$ \vec{g} \times \nabla c = 0 \\ \nabla \ln(b) \times \vec{g} = R \; . $$
Unfortunately, the characteristic lines of the pde's are tangential to the boundary on $\partial \Omega$. So the interior of the domain is not connected to the boundary. I was hoping there are other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by noticing that we need
$$
\begin{split}
0 &= \nabla\times\nabla c = \nabla\times\frac gb
= \nabla\frac1b \times g + \frac1b \nabla\times g
= -\frac{\nabla b}{b^2} \times g + \frac Rb .
\end{split}
$$
Multiplying by $b$ you get
$$
\nabla(\log b) \times g = R.
$$
This is a linear first order partial differential equation, whose solution is of the form $b=\exp(\tilde f+f_0)$, where $\tilde f$ is a particular solution to the inhomogeneous PDE $\nabla f \times g = R$ and $f_0$ is a solution to the homogeneous one. The PDE is solvable as long as $g$ is not orthogonal to $\partial\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is your domain, the positive quadrant) and boundary value for $b$ is compatible with the characteristic lines.
You can find more pieces of information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation), [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveLinearAndQuasiLinearFirstOrderPDEs.html), and [here](http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~prasad/prasad/Linear_Quasi.pdf).

Once you have found $b$, $g/b$ is irrotational, therefore you find $c$ such that $\nabla c=g/b$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the characteristic lines of the pde's are tangential to the boundary on $\partial \Omega$.